# IBM Cloud Compose PostgresSQL FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, compose-db

Provisioned an IBM Cloud Compose PostgreSQL instance. Then tried to connect the instance to the Watson Studio.

Although establishing a connection works fine, when I try to save retraining configuration getting the following error message.

Error: Unhandled exception of type PSQLException with message: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off

I do not think I can ssh to the db host and just change the pg_hba.conf file.

I do not think this is a possibility as the IBM Cloud Compose PostgreSQL is server less instance (I think).

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you connect? Do you use a connection asset? Is this connection asset using the "Compose for PostgreSQL" or "PostgreSQL" type of connection? The "Compose for PostgreSQL" type of connection asset uses TLS, so should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means you are trying to connect to the Database without TLS. Databases for PostgreSQL will reject unsecured connections.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-security-compliance#protection-against-unauthorized-access

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-external-app

Comment: Thanks Joshua, But connecting from the Watson Studio how we enable TLS. Because it seems this control is not given to the user.

Comment: @KosiB it depends on how you're adding the database. How are you using it? In a Python notebook or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the nodes accessing Postgres to pg_hba.conf file in the postgres server. For example,if the CIDR for the nodes connecting to Postgres is 192.168.1.0/24, then an entry like the following is required.

```
# TYPE   DATABASE         USER        ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only local    all               all                          peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all               all        127.0.0.1/32      ident host     all               all        192.168.1.0/24      trust
```

You have to find where to do this in IBM Cloud

Comment: That is the question, where to do this in IBM Cloud